# how to code java that using method to display and user can enter input

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

class isipadu{
    Double jejari, jejari1, tinggi, isipadu;

    void papar(){
        System.out.println("jejari: "+jejari);
        System.out.println("tinggi: "+tinggi);
        System.out.println("isipadu: "+isipadu);
    } 
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        BufferedReader stdin=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("masukkan jejari : ");
        jejari=Double.parseDouble(stdin.readLine());
        System.out.print("masukkan tinggi : ");
        tinggi=Double.parseDouble(stdin.readLine());

        jejari1=jejari*jejari;
        isipadu=3.142*jejari1*tinggi;

        isipadu P1=new isipadu();
        P1.papar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Title should resume the problem, the post should explain it, here it"s empty of explanation. You need to build a constructor for `isipadu` to get the param for it, also Java convention : class name UpperCamelCase

Answer (score 0):

You're in static method and cannot set the variable since variables are instance variables,

Create a new object of isipadu, set variables on that object and call papar on that, like this:

```java
isipadu p1 = new isipadu();
BufferedReader stdin=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

System.out.print("masukkan jejari : ");
p1.jejari=Double.parseDouble(stdin.readLine());

System.out.print("masukkan tinggi : ");
p1.tinggi=Double.parseDouble(stdin.readLine());

p1.jejari1=jejari*jejari;
p1.isipadu=3.142*jejari1*tinggi;

P1.papar();
```